# Completing the WCF implementation picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, wcf

I have seen many examples and even worked previously on some WCF code perhaps without fully understanding it. Now that I am trying to implement it on my own I cant seem to get it to work so im looking for some tips!

Here is my situation:

Good -I can build the service library and host it in service application OR in IIS7, both giving me successful results in that I can see the service via typing in the location of the .svc file in my browser.

Bad -I need to connect to the service via javascript, but connecting to localhost via json gives me "No Transport"  and alternatively if i try to  connect to my hosting server via jsonp gives me 'success' but with undefined response (should be a hello world response..)

Here is my config file on the service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
 </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Here is my JS for json:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://10.8.8.53/Schools/SchoolsService.svc/TestSchoolVal1",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 10000,
    data: "4",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    }
});
```

The jsonp code is the same just has jsonp instead of json and a jsonpcallback function defined.

Any suggestions? i need to get both the localhost and my IIS7!

I have also tried including external reference in visual studio which generates a lot more web.config - but i want to access the svn via javascript, not backend code!!

more info: the service namespace is SchoolsWCF, class is Service1, service file is SchoolsService.svc, method is TestSchoolVal1 which takes an int parameter, and the localhost hosting app is a windows console app.