# Can you consume ASMX webservices from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, web-services, asmx

Can you consume ASMX webservices directly from Javascript / JQuery?
I am having issues hosting/developing a good solution with WCF so I wanted to see what other options are out there as far as connecting my already-developed front end to some backend C# code.
For reference there is also a question out there regarding my WCF issue here: [Completing the WCF implementation picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472074/completing-the-wcf-implementation-picture)

Update: I would also accept as an answer, an alternative solution for me to access c# code. I already have my frontend developed, so I just want to avoid having to replace my GUI elements with ASP.NET runat-server controls! Thanks!

Comment: An ASMX web service is just a SOAP web service. You can call it just like any other web service. What did you try?

Comment: @ Panagiotis: What I am asking is actually if you can directly access the methods exposed in the ASMX service via javascript. If you read above, I had tried WCF first because that is possible there, but now im looking for other options. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, ASMX web services are standard SOAP services. And yes, you can call its methods like below:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "WebService.asmx/WebMethodName",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: "json"
});
```

You can read more on it in [this great tutorial](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/).

Comment: Unbelievably simple. Why did this work so easily and WCF caused me so much grief. Also that article link you posted was fantastic, and the comments on it underneath helped me with IIS integration. You have saved my week!! Peace

Comment: Glad you got your answer :)